# How do I fix continuous crash on a minecraft 1.7.10 forge eclipse environment?

Tags: minecraft-forge

How do I fix continuous crash on a Minecraft 1.7.10 forge eclipse environment?

Crash Report:

```
[15:52:25] [main/INFO] [GradleStart]: Extra: [] [15:52:25] [main/INFO] [GradleStart]: Running with arguments: [--userProperties, {},
--assetsDir, C:/Users/JmsG/.gradle/caches/minecraft/assets, --assetIndex, 1.7.10, --accessToken, {REDACTED}, --version, 1.7.10, --tweakClass, cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker, --tweakClass, net.minecraftforge.gradle.tweakers.CoremodTweaker] [15:52:25] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker [15:52:25] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Using primary tweak class name cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker [15:52:25] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name net.minecraftforge.gradle.tweakers.CoremodTweaker [15:52:25] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker [15:52:25] [main/INFO] [FML]: Forge Mod Loader version 7.99.40.1614 for Minecraft 1.7.10 loading [15:52:25] [main/INFO] [FML]: Java is Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, version 1.8.0_73, running on Windows 8:x86:6.2, installed at C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_73 [15:52:25] [main/INFO] [FML]: Managed to load a deobfuscated Minecraft name- we are in a deobfuscated environment. Skipping runtime deobfuscation [15:52:25] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class net.minecraftforge.gradle.tweakers.CoremodTweaker [15:52:25] [main/INFO] [GradleStart]: Injecting location in coremod cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.FMLCorePlugin [15:52:25] [main/INFO] [GradleStart]: Injecting location in coremod net.minecraftforge.classloading.FMLForgePlugin [15:52:25] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLInjectionAndSortingTweaker [15:52:25] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLDeobfTweaker [15:52:25] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name net.minecraftforge.gradle.tweakers.AccessTransformerTweaker [15:52:25] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLInjectionAndSortingTweaker [15:52:25] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLInjectionAndSortingTweaker [15:52:25] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.CoreModManager$FMLPluginWrapper [15:52:25] [main/ERROR] [FML]: The binary patch set is missing. Either you are in a development environment, or things are not going to work! [15:52:27] [main/ERROR] [FML]: FML appears to be missing any signature data. This is not a good thing [15:52:27] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.CoreModManager$FMLPluginWrapper [15:52:27] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLDeobfTweaker [15:52:28] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class net.minecraftforge.gradle.tweakers.AccessTransformerTweaker [15:52:28] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.TerminalTweaker [15:52:28] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.TerminalTweaker [15:52:28] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Launching wrapped minecraft {net.minecraft.client.main.Main} [15:52:29] [main/INFO]: Setting user: Player647 [15:52:30] [Client thread/INFO]: LWJGL Version: 2.9.1 [15:52:31] [Client thread/ERROR]: Couldn't set pixel format org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method) ~[lwjgl-2.9.1.jar:?]
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52) ~[lwjgl-2.9.1.jar:?]
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:252) ~[lwjgl-2.9.1.jar:?]
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306) ~[lwjgl-2.9.1.jar:?]
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848) ~[lwjgl-2.9.1.jar:?]
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757) ~[lwjgl-2.9.1.jar:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.ForgeHooksClient.createDisplay(ForgeHooksClient.java:327) ~[ForgeHooksClient.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.startGame(Minecraft.java:474) [Minecraft.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:942) [Minecraft.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:164) [Main.class:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_73]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleStartCommon.launch(Unknown Source) [start/:?]
    at GradleStart.main(Unknown Source) [start/:?] [15:52:32] [Client thread/INFO] [STDOUT]: [net.minecraft.client.Minecraft:displayCrashReport:388]: ---- Minecraft Crash Report ---- // Sorry :(

Time: 27/8/2016 3:52 μμ Description: Initializing game

org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:252)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.startGame(Minecraft.java:494)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:942)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
    at net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleStartCommon.launch(Unknown Source)
    at GradleStart.main(Unknown Source)
```

A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:

```
-- Head -- Stacktrace:
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:252)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.startGame(Minecraft.java:494)

-- Initialization -- Details: Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:942)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
    at net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleStartCommon.launch(Unknown Source)
    at GradleStart.main(Unknown Source)

-- System Details -- Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.7.10
    Operating System: Windows 8 (x86) version 6.2
    Java Version: 1.8.0_73, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 953670520 bytes (909 MB) / 1060372480 bytes (1011 MB) up to 1060372480 bytes (1011 MB)
    JVM Flags: 3 total; -Xincgc -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M
    AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    FML: 
    Launched Version: 1.7.10
    LWJGL: 2.9.1
    OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
    GL Caps: 
    Is Modded: Definitely; Client brand changed to 'fml,forge'
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: []
    Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    Vec3 Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    Anisotropic Filtering: Off (1) [15:52:32] [Client thread/INFO] [STDOUT]: [net.minecraft.client.Minecraft:displayCrashReport:398]:
```

#@!@# Game crashed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.

Means that the context of `OpenGL` during rendering was broken.

Since `LWJGL` is throwing the exception, it's probably not your own rendering code. If such is the case, refer to here - http://hopper.minecraft.net/help/pixel-format-not-accelerated/

```
org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
```

However if you're doing custom rendering of any sort, then it's you're OpenGL context being broken and not restored. What this means is that If you start rendering, you have to also stop rendering.

I know this reply is a tad late, but hopefully it stands to help others.

Answer (score 0):

You probaly don't have your graphics drivers installed, or not open gl compatible drivers.

> OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.

Try updating your graphics drivers with something decent, or research if your graphics card even supports openGL